# Using ng-class with if statement on function derived expression instead of ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to apply conditional css using ng-class but it seems that it does not work on expression derived from function such as

```
$scope.totalFeatureLength = function() {
  return $scope.items.reduce(function(current, item) { return current + item.Fiscal_Year_1; }, 0);
};
```

HTML

```
 <div class="progress">
  <div ng-class="{'progress-bar progress-bar-info': {{totalFeatureLength()number:2}}<10, 'progress-bar progress-bar-danger': {{totalFeatureLength()|number:2}}>=10}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{totalFeatureLength()| number:2}}%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{totalFeatureLength()| number:2}}%;">
    {{totalFeatureLength()| number:2}}%
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine when used directly on ng-model items but it does not on the expression from functions. Do I need to create a directive or it can be done using this existing method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-class already takes an expression, so you don't need/want the double-curly braces and can just use JS.

For example you can do this:

```
<div ng-class="{'progress-bar progress-bar-info': totalFeatureLength() < 10}">
```

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3D9A/2/)

Comment: Thanks kayakDave for the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: One more thing to note for this problem is that we need to use "{{ }}" expression for aria-valuenow and width.